# Pass kendocalendar date to sql database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

Scenario:
I know this is a simple datetime conversion, but i'm new to backend and conversions. So please help: I use mvc with ajax to pass the date from kendocalender to scheduler to save it in database:
Here is my code:
 controller.cs

```
public int insertnote(string model,DateTime kendodate)
         {
             tblDailyNotes Dnote = new tblDailyNotes();
             int noteid = 0;
             //note.RealDate=Convert.ToString(
            Dnote.Note = model;
            Dnote.RealDate = kendodate;
            noteid = _scheduler.InsertDailynote(Dnote);
             return noteid;
         }
```

index.cshtml

```
  $("#dailynotes").change(function () {
            debugger;
            alert("Changed");
            var dailynotes = $('#dailynotes').val();

        var calendar = $("#SchedulerCalendar2").data("kendoCalendar");

        var cal = calendar.value(new Date());
        alert(cal);
        $.ajax({
           ![enter image description here][1]
            type: "POST",
            url: window.location.pathname + "Scheduler/insertnote",

            data: {model:dailynotes, kendodate: cal }
        })
         .success(function (result) {
             alert("note saved successfully");
         });
    });
```

Question:

this is the cal alert

[image]

How do I convert this output from kendocalendar to "2013-09-01 13:27:14.480"(yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss.sss) this format using jquery to save it in database through controller function. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

you can convert string to DateTime by DateTime.Parse

[take a look at this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-parse)

Answer (score -1):

I agree with user2675751's solution.  However, I would recomend using Datetime.TryParse() as this will not throw an exception and return a bool to indicate success or failure.  This point is covered in the link user2675751 has provided. It is generally best not to trust data coming from the client.